# How can I create a master branch from my develop branch in BitBucket/Git?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow

I built a site in a branch called 'develop' to meet internal requirements for pushing to our development server.

I now need to push the developed project into the master branch which is currently empty. How can I do that?

Comment: The branch is *empty* or *does not exists*? What is the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: git branch -a outputs: develop, master, remotes/origin/develop, remotes/origin/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push *local* develop branch into "remote" branch master, then you can do this:

`git push the-remote develop:master`

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: git checkout -b master

Step 2: git pull origin develop